# MariaDB max_open_files over 600k

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Questions about max_open_files has been asked a thousand times. However, most cases recommend setting the limit to 65535 or so. However, our warning is that mysql tried to open over 640k files. We increased the limit to 768k. However, documentation suggests that 1024x1024 (1048576) is the linux limit.

Basically, is there a way to find out why we have so many open files? We only have 1 medium sized db (less than 300mb), and 6-8 very small dbs. If 1024x1024 is really the limit, in 6 months or less we could seemingly exceed that. And then what? Will the db implode?

Comment: I don't think there is a `max_open_files`.  There is `open_files_limit` and `Opened_files`.  Please check the spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL also open one "file" for other things, but the main cause for a high number of open files are connections.

MySQL and almost all database behaves like this, each connection counts as one opened file.

You can check the number of connections with:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE '%Threads_connected%';
```

Probably you'll need to adjust **max_connections** parameter and look for persistent connections and pools from applications perspective.

If you database are in trouble, stucked connections or some kind of "dos", you can check the processes in execution with:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

And eventually kill something strange with:

```
KILL <pid>; -- the id from the command above
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Connections counting as open files explains a lot. We do receive a lot of bots and dos attacks. We will try those commands you listed and see where it takes us.

Comment: If helps, vote as the right one :D, anyway, if you're using Linux a fail2ban probably will help. And just to warn you, a database should never be accessible from public interfaces. You'll need an VPN or SSH tunnel to administer. The application should connect from inside.

Comment: Our db is only accessible from 127.0.0.1. Bad bots or brute forcing will still open lots of tables right? And that counts as open files? Or are we misunderstanding.

Comment: Any connection, failedm or notm will open a file for a moment. But if your database is only accesible from localhost, bots and other things can't stabilish a tcp connection to create a file descriptor. Your own application with persistent connections... maybe?